# Scrapy calling spider other than the one specified on the command line

Tags: scrapy

```
(P6Svenv)malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/P6/P6Svenv/test2/test2/spiders$     scrapy crawl zomd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.0.3.post6-g2d688cd', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 209, in __init__
super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 115, in __init__
self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 296, in _get_spider_loader
return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 30, in from_settings
return cls(settings)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 21, in __init__
for module in walk_modules(name):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
submod = import_module(fullpath)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/malikarumi/Projects/P6/P6Svenv/test2/test2/spiders/t350_crawl.py", line 36
def parse_item(self, response):
                              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Do you see it? Scrapy isn't even calling the spider I specified on the command line!

I see that super in the traceback, but all my t350's are derived from CrawlSpider. zomd is subclassed from scrapy.Spider. Why is this happening and what do I do about it?

Comment: @LearnAWK: yes, that's right, and in this case 'zomd' is in zomd.py, while t350_crawl is in t350_crawl.py, so my issue remains unanswered. However, Django has a command, I think it is called 'check', that goes thru all the code in a project looking for errors; I wonder if this is a similar feature at work in Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

Spider's name doesn't equal to the file name.  It is defined within the spider file by the second line below:

```
class CAPjobSpider(Spider):
    name = "spider_name"
```

The above spider's name is "**spider_name**", even if the file may be  "New_York.py".